# groovy ArrayList casting (note: appears to be a bug with the runtime error line identification, not ArrayList casting)

Tags: grails, groovy

NOTE TO READER:  Thanks to Tim's help below, I was able to resolve the problem.  The root of the problem wasn't the ArrayList casting, but the fact that the runtime engine pointed the error to the wrong line, i.e. the one I show below where I access the list.  The real error was 4 lines below that, where I made a mistake assigning an element into the element I just retrieved.

I've got a small Result class (at bottom of my grails controller class), and then in my code, I do

```
ArrayList<Result> bestResults = new ArrayList<Result>()
```

to help the compiler know what bestResults is (but tried other forms below).  Then, I try to access this arraylist, via:

```
for (int r = 0; r < topSet; r++) {
   Result res = bestResults[r] as Result
```

and, I get an "Cannot cast object ... to blahblah.Result" run-time error.

I've tried other variations of both, namely:

```
ArrayList bestResults = new ArrayList()
```

with

```
Result res = (Result) bestResults[r]
```

or just

```
Result res = bestResults.get(r) as Result
```

and I always get the same casting error.  I just can't seem to please the Groovy "engine" / JVM! :-) :-(

Can you please assist?

-----------------------   The more full code -----------------

The Result class is at the bottom of my grails controller (main) class, namely:

```
class Result {
   float factor
   def results = null // NOTE: this will hold an array of float
}
```

Then, in the controller, I do the following, intializing bestResults to bogus values:

```
 def results = new float[2 * deltaRange + 1] as float[] // the results array gets assigned to bestResults AFTER the error I get, so it seems non-relevant

 ArrayList<Result> bestResults = new ArrayList<Result>()
 Result fakeResult = new Result(factor: 100.0f, results: null)
 for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
        bestResults.add(r,fakeResult)
 }
```

Then, when I go to insert a real result, I run into the problem, doing:

```
for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
  Result res = bestResults.get(r) as Result
```

or doing

```
  Result res = bestResults[r] as Result
```

or

```
   Result res = bestResults[r]
```

All give the error:

```
Message: Cannot cast object '[F@4f5b6d' with class '[F' to class 'alwaysbetter.Result'
```

*** After this error, I have the code that does:

```
bestResults[r].results =  results
```

where results is defined as an array of floats at the top, namely:

```
def results = new float[2 * deltaRange + 1] as float[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, the problem is the last bit of information you gave...

```
def results = new float[2 * deltaRange + 1] as float[]
```

makes no sense in groovy, to get a float array of `2 * deltaRange + 1` elements, your best bet is probably:

```
float[] results = [ 0 ] * ( 2 * deltaRange + 1 )
```

#### Original answer

Is this inside Java code?

When you say *"main class"*, what do you mean?

How does this relate to grails?

This works in groovy:

```
class Result {
  String name
}

ArrayList<Result> bestResults = new ArrayList<Result>()

bestResults << new Result( name:'tim' )

for (int r = 0; r < bestResults.size(); r++) {
   Result res = bestResults[r]
   println res
}
```

Or, more groovily:

```
bestResults.each { Result r -> println r }
```

#### Edit after question update

That error message says you are trying to convert an `array of float` (ie: `float[]`) into a Result object

There must be something missing from the code you have posted, as if I paste it into a groovy console, it works fine

It's a bit odd though...

You do realise you're adding the same `Result` instance to the List 10 times don't you?  Not 10 separate instances?

Comment: Tim, I mean (in grails) I have a BlahController class, and then at the bottom, I create a little Result class.

Comment: @RayK can you edit your question to post a cut-down (but more complete) example of what you are trying to do, and the error it gives?  As you can see, the code works, so it must be an issue with something else you're doing

Comment: @RayK Updated answer...  think you're still missing something...  is that the actual code that's failing?  Because I can't see how it can be failing...

Comment: Yah Tim, it is.  But I think you're hitting on something.  The results I'm assigning into the Result class is: def results = new float[2 * deltaRange + 1] as float[].

Comment: ... I'm okay with the same instance of the bogus result ... I just want something to compare to as I generate the real results, sticking the best results in there;  they'll all have a factor of less than 1.0.  @TIM - note, I don't even assign that float results array until after I get the error above, retrieving the object.  Also, I tried the code you posted, and it works. So it has to do with the float array somehow (which supposedly isn't in the picture yet ... hmm).

Comment: @RayK Any chance you could add that code to your question then?  It seems highly relevant, and my crystal ball is currently broken ;-)

Comment: TIM:  I got it.  The compiler is telling me I have an error on the line:  Result res = bestResults[r] as Result, instead of the real error 4 lines below it, namely I had an:  bestResults[r] = results, instead of bestResults[r].results = results.  So, this is an error in the runtimes error message display, it would seem?

Comment: @RayK added solution to top of answer...  You can't make arrays like you used to in Java with Groovy (as you were shown in your previous question)

Comment: Tim, that array declaration ends up working fine (I thought I was doing the same thing, in the "as float[]" part at the end, but perhaps not.  So, the whole thing that threw me off here was 1) it telling me the wrong line, and 2) not knowing what "[F" is.  Now I know!  Seems like a bug in the way the errors are presented.  Thanks much for your help, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Tim - I updated the question description at the top, to reveal the error/problem.  Please let me know if you think this should be submitted as a bug with a terse example.

Comment: @RayK I'd make doubly sure it was giving the wrong line number first...  It might just have been you misreading it as your class and property are both called result, this -- from experience -- can lead to jumping to conclusions, and misreading errors ;-)  Glad it's solved now though :-)

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Yah,  new Grails 2.0, while the error output is very nice, it's definitely giving the wrong line number ... I went their multiple times scratching my head :-(   I'll file a bug with a condensed example.  Thanks again, Ray